# Java Sort Data From A File Method writeToFile

Tags: java

I have to write a method to write data to a file. It has to take an array of integers as a parameter and write them to a file, but I am getting an error on these lines:

```
Integer[] x = val.toArray(new Integer[val.size(25)]);
if (x < 0) break;

public static void writeToFile (String filename, int[] x) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter outputWriter = new PrintWriter("integers.txt");
    System.out.println("Please enter 25 scores.");
    System.out.println("You must hit enter after you enter each score.");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int score = 0;
    while (score < 25) {
        int val = sc.nextInt();
        Integer[] x = val.toArray(new Integer[val.size(25)]);
        if (x < 0) break;
        outputWriter.println(x);
        score++; }
    outputWriter.flush();
    outputWriter.close();
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: `val` is an `int` and thus doesn't have any member methods like `size()` or `toArray()`. And `x` is an array which you can't compare to an integer literal. I guess you want `x.length < 0` here.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things. First off, you are trying to do things that are not possible to do with an int. Look at the ever helpful java API when trying to use a class:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Next, if I was writing your program (which I'm not and I do not intend to), I would watch your instantiations. The array is being instantiated every loop which means that you will have a new array every time the user puts in a value. Meaning all the previous numbers are going to be lost. Also, take the integer array out of the parameter. You aren't even using it in the method.

Instantiate your array outside of the loop with a size of 25 elements:

int[] array = new int[25];

Now, you can place the items in this array every loop like this:

array[score] = val;

This places the value in the indexes 0 -> 24. It seems to me that in order to truly understand how to do this program you are going to have to have a refresher on arrays and how they work.

Finally, the computer sees this method as a sequence. So, line by line think about what is happening on your program. Ideally, this is what should be happening.

Instantiate your objects: the scanner, the array (where the ints are stored), the Print writer

give instructions to the user how to use the program.

run a loop 25 times doing this:
- scanning in an int
- placing the int into the array at the appropriate index

write the array into the file

flush the writer.

close the writer.

Comment: to keep the user from adding a negative value... do this after the scan for the next int | while(val < 0){ System.out.println("Please add a positive number"); val = sc.nextInt();}